# Uno - ESP32 SoftwareSerial communication won't work

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, esp32

I have two boards, Uno and ESP32 and my goal is to send data from the Uno to the ESP. I made a voltage divider so my ESP doesn't get fried and I use the communication only in **ONE** way, strictly UNO -> ESP32. I use PIN 9 from my UNO to send data and RX2 (16) from my ESP to receive the data. How ever, I get errors and can't make it work.

This is my Uno code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial softPort(-1, 9);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
softPort.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
softPort.print("100");
delay(2000);

}
```

and my ESP code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define RXD2 16
#define TXD2 -1

SoftwareSerial Serial2(RXD2, TXD2); // RX, TX

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);

}

void loop() {
Serial.println("Data received:");
Serial.println(Serial2.read());
delay(200);

}
```

I'm getting an error that says

> no matching function for call to 'SoftwareSerial::begin(int, int, int, int)'

Comment: Um.... why would you use SoftwareSerial on the ESP32 to access the secondary *hardware* UART?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the ESP32 you would *never* use SoftwareSerial except under *exceptional* circumstances.

The ESP32 has three hardware UARTs that can be mapped to *any* pin combination on the board.

The general usage is:

```
HardwareSerial Serial2(1); // Use UART channel 1

void setup() {
    Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
}
```

UARTs are numbered 0-2 where 0 is pre-assigned to the TX/RX (USB connection) pins and is used for debugging and programming.  UARTs 1 and 2 are not normally assigned to anywhere and you can use them as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir. One question, in `Serial2(1)`, 1 stands for RX1 and TX1? In my case, where I use RX2 and TX2, do I have to use`Serial2(2)`? And do I have to change my wiring in order to use HardwareSerial? This is my wiring right now: https://i.imgur.com/KvIZQdx.png @Majenko

Comment: No. 1 stands for UART 1. Where you connect it to is up to you. The UARTs don't have any standard pins (except UART 0 for the bootloader). It's only when you call `begin()` that you tell it which pins to use. Until then it has no pins. RX1 and TX1 are just labels that coincide with the bootloader / debug pins. You could use 1 or 2 in the constructor and it will make no difference - it'll just be using a different UART module inside the chip.

Comment: I get it now, thank you once again and sorry for my ignorance :) Lastly, can you please confirm if my wiring is correct and if I can use it for HardwareSerial?

Comment: GPIO3 is the default for UART0 RX. That's the bootloader / USB connection on most boards. You should pick something else. Not one of the RTC pins though. Anything between 13 and 33 are good choices.